# How can I make VSCode run a node app like "npm start"?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have a node app with the `package.json` like so:

```
{
    "name": "myexpressapp",   
    "version": "0.0.99",   
    "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"   },  
    //etc
}
```

and in `app.js` I have

```
console.log ("Running version: "+process.env.npm_package_version);
```

When I run `npm start` in the command prompt this logs

> Running version: 0.0.99

When I start (press <kbd>F5</kbd>) in VS Code this logs

> Running version: undefined

What change do I need to make to `launch.json` to start the app in VS Code as if I had entered `npm start` in the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I can now get it to run (but not debug) using the following `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch via NPM#3",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [

                "start"
            ],
            "port": 5858,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program#1",
            "program": "app.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }

    ]
}
```